# Pattern or strategy for showing hierarchical response content?

Tags: tables, hierarchy, tree

I'm expanding my app's capabilities from this:

[image: Current design for simple numeric result]

...to displaying all the **rules** that were applied, **results** for each rule, **rule description**, and **link to more info**.

I'd really appreciate pointers to apps which solve this kind of detail/detail display well. Here is how a couple of other apps solve this problem. I feel like there can be better ways to do it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit: here's an interesting solution on duolingo.com:

[image]

Comment: The image above the following quote does not relate to the words: "...to displaying all the rules that were applied, results for each rule, rule description, and link to more info." There are no visible rules, no visible application of them, no results for each rule, and and no rule descriptions. Nor a link. I'm completely uncertain what you're attempting to do.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar to the duolingo solution: a table that allows the user to sort the applied rules into various orders such as by name, by last run, by severity of condition/urgency of fix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a question that requires a combination of understanding the data and information architecture for the best user experience when presenting complex or layered information to users.

In terms of data presentation, you want to achieve a balance between visual harmony (i.e. present similar types of data and information in a similar way) so that there consistency and alignment of the data.

In terms of information architecture, you want to achieve the best logic for showing relationships between the different rules (e.g. weighting, importance, rank, etc.) so that the user can immediately see the most important items and be able to drill down into more detail if required.

Some of the examples shown here don't really address both aspects equally, so you should consider taking the best features and working them into your final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked this app - productboard.com (not the dev or designer from there) - I think you may explore it online to get the relevant impression.

Overall I'd say it's hard to tell something meaningful without knowing the use case.

- in general old math rule "enough and sufficient" works for such dashboards well. Place as little as possible. Only what the user needs for EVERY item in a table (if you have it);
- if the case requires an extra note for SOME items - place it in ToolTip
- charts and bars are easier to read and they split text blocks into digestible chunks;
- do several different (very) screens - you will feel what is right and you will be able to get the constructive feedback
  good luck :)
  [image: productboard sample scren]

Comment: What is it about productboard that would help with the question? If the site goes offline tomorrow, it would be nice for your answer to still be relevant.

Comment: Thank you @Nash - that is a valid point, I've updated my answer